# RestTemplate with client-certificates

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, resttemplate

I would like to use client-certificates to communicate between spring-boot applications. My problem is, that don't know how to configure `RestTemplate` to use a client-certificate to authenticate against the other application.

If possible i would prefer to solve this problem with the Spring Boot properties instead of writing code - but any solution is better then none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking to implement a two way SSL authentication. It will have to be supported by whatever `ClientHttpRequestFactory` is configured in your `RestTemplate`.

If you use Spring Boot defaults, that is standard `javax.net` stack, take a look at [Spring Boot Client authentication demo](https://github.com/viniciusccarvalho/boot-two-way-ssl-example). Apache HttpClient and other libraries might require a different setup.